# probleme with jquery_ujs and rails-ujs problem ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am new in rails and ruby, I just started like 1 week ago.

I'm trying to do a chat between 2 people on rails, with jquery for the ajax part.

Everything works, but I got this error that I don't understand and it really bothers me

Image to the error (couldn't include it with an image balise)
https://ibb.co/KKjKLPf

VM17:2082 Uncaught Error: If you load both jquery_ujs and rails-ujs, use rails-ujs only.

I understand that I use jquery_ujs and rails-ujs at the same time, and rails want me to only use rails-ujs.

My main page (index.hmtl.erb) has this as code

```
<h1>welcome to the chat  </h1>
<div id='conv'>
    <div id='message'>
    </div>
    <div id='sendmsg'>
    <%= form_tag "/", method: "post" do %>
        <input type='hidden' name='name' value='phil'/>
        <input id='tex' type="text" name="message" />
        <input id='sen' type="submit" value="send" />
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

My javascript is like this

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    setInterval(refreshMessage,3000);
    function refreshMessage(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/chatBoard',
            success: function(data){
                $('#message').html(data);
            },
            error : function(){
                $('#message').html('error');
            } 
        })
    };
});
```

This ajax send to the server a GET to '/chatBoard' and it will return all messages in the database with this script.

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
<%= message.name %> :
<%= message.message %>
<% end %>
```

I try to find a solution, but I am still stuck so I post it here, I would like to make this work but without this error.
What should I do? Change my ajax request with a CoffeeScript one? Haven't learned CoffeeScript yet :/

edit:

Hello, i don't know why but removing something in application.js make the trick

```
// require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("custom")
```

i just did a comment on the require("@rails/ujs").start() and the error don't show up anymore and the code still work :/ weard

Answer (score 1):

My guess is in your `application.js` file, you have

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery_ujs
```

If you remove the `//= require jquery_ujs`, the error should go away.

Comment: hello , thanks you for your anwser :D
but i only got this in the application.js  
`require("@rails/ujs").start().  
require("turbolinks").start().  
require("@rails/activestorage").start().    
require("channels").  
require("custom")`

Comment: sorry about the format. i couldn't find how to do break line in code backstick

Comment: thanks i comment the rails/ujs and it work , don't know why :D

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you are importing two libraries for the same purpose, `jquery-ujs`, and `rails-ujs`. So you need to leave just one depending on the Rails version you are using. If your version is 5.0 or prior to that you need to use `jquery-ujs` but if you are using Rails 5.1 onwards you need to use `rails-ujs`. Additionally, if you need support for jQuery, as you mentioned in the comment, you need to add the `jquery-rails` gem in your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` in the console, and in the `application.js` add `//= require jquery` (above the line where you are importing `jquery-ujs` or `rails-ujs`).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that if I use rails-ujs with jquery-rails, my $.ajax calls only work if I send along the authenticity token!

```
$.ajax({data: {authenticity_token: $('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content}});
```

Plus obviously whatever else is being sent...